Expo routes does not support 'swipe back'?
I'm using Expo Router.
Swipe to back does not work when using Link. Is this intentional in Expo Router?
Reproducible & minimal codes is here: https://github.com/ygnoh/expo-router-swipe

Press Navigate to screen two in index
And Swipe left to right to go back in two page. -> does not work

If it is not supported, it there any way to implement it?


The problem was caused by not applying Stack to the layout.
Once I applied the Stack, it worked fine.
